# unable install @angular/cli on my system

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

I want to install @angular/cli on windows 7 but i received these error 
npm ERR Unexpected....

[image: You can see errors that show up on command line in here]

Comment: Try to open run with administrator @zivar

Comment: Try doing this `npm cache clean --force`